# how to check the string is valid date format or not (format should be in : YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

how do I check whether string is valid date format or not?
format should be in : YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

```js
console.log(moment(moment("FLAT 10").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').isValid())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image]

above code should return false but its giving me output as TRUE

I tried this code too but still its failing...

[image]
how to solve this? how to compare string and date using moment

js fiddle link:
[jsfiddle.net/8Lwrvcep](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lwrvcep)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] as this should work: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lwrvcep/

Comment: @Andreas thanks for adding jsFiddle link, will take about this from next time onward?...do you have any solution for it?

Comment: There's no solution because there's no problem as you can see in the fiddle and the snippet Phil added. In both cases `.isValid()` returns (as expected) `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response will be always true because the parameter of the moment is a valid date and you are just applying a format to it and check if it is valid

To compare dates without checking the format use:
`moment('2017-01-01T00:00:00').isSame(moment('2017-01-01T00:00:00'))`

`moment('string','format you want to check for').isValid()` if you don't provide format and test `moment("ASD 10").isValid()` this will always will be valid because it has a integer and it and converts to OCTOBER beecause as I said is the 10th month of the year

`console.log(moment("ASD 10",'YYYY-MMM DD h:mm A').isValid());` // returns false
`console.log(moment("ASD 10").isValid());` //returns true

Comment: `moment("FLAT 10")` is not a valid date o.O

Comment: Try and see console.log(moment("FLAT 10").isValid());

Comment: `"FLAT 10"` is not a valid date, hence moments `.isValid()` won't return `true` -> https://jsfiddle.net/xcdgruf3/

Comment: @Andreas @ Alexandru Corlan moment("FLAT 10").isValid() giving me valid date in my code

Comment: I know, that is because it converts the FLAT 10 in OCTOMBER because is the 10th month of the year

Comment: @vivekpadelkar but we don't understand what you want to compare, please update your question if you don't want to compare any 2 dates

Comment: @AlexandruCorlan simply I want to check whether the string have valid date format   as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss or not if i enter "FLAT 10" OR anything apart from date it should give invalid date message

Comment: @AlexandruCorlan i have updated the question please check again

Comment: Updated the response with explanations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231357/discussion-between-vivek-padelkar-and-alexandru-corlan).

Comment: @AlexandruCorlan as per your explanation i tried your code                                                                                       console.log(moment("ASD 10",'YYYY-MMM DD h:mm A').isValid()); // should return  returns false //      
BUT still getting output as TRUE

Comment: Join the chat and we'll discuss